# SonarQube: Unsupported class file major version 58 error when using Java 11

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

I am trying to execute `mvn sonar:sonar` command on spring boot project

```
$ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<URL> -Dsonar.login=<Token>
```

When I run the above command I get error message

```
Can not execute Findbugs: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
```

I am using java 11 in my project and sonarqube also using `OpenJDK 11.0.7+10`. Java 8 projects work without any issues. I set the java version in pom.xml as shown below

**pom.xml**

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Which version of the sonarqube finbugs plugin do you use?

Comment: I am using built-in FindBugs profile

Comment: I ask for the findbus version in sonarqube not for a profie. https://www.sonarplugins.com/findbugs

Comment: I see version 3.11.1

Comment: Take a look into the sonarqube admin interface, check the version and update the plugin.

Comment: As soon as I saw the update, I clicked on it. However I still got error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58` initially but the analysis is running. I will let you know if it completes successfully

Comment: @Jens Analysis ran successfully despite the initial exception. Please post this as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed sonarqube-findbugs plugin is not java 11 compatible. Go into the Adminmistration --> Marketplace view and update this plugin